# Retrieve a row data from database using JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I wrote a Java EE application to convert currencies. The user enters the value to convert, the "from" currency and the "to" currency, retrieving the conversion rate from a database table.

! [fragment of the table in Netbeans] https://s16.postimg.org/8m242gyyd/Screen_Shot_2016_12_03_at_23_45_23.png

My currency controller has the following code:

```
public double convertTo(double value, String fromCur, String toCur) {
    TypedQuery<Rate> query = em.createQuery(""
            + "SELECT c FROM Rate c WHERE c.fromCur = 'BRA' AND c.toCur = 'EUR'", Rate.class);

    query.setParameter("tocurrency", toCur);
    query.setParameter("fromcurrency", fromCur);

    Rate result = query.getSingleResult();

    if (result == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Can't find rate");
    }

    return value * result.getValue();

}
```

My goal is to get the rate from "BRA" to "EUR" for example and calculate the converted amount and return it. When I run the application I get the exception:

> getsingleresult() did not retrieve any entities

There must be a simpler way to retrieve the rate from the database to calculate this conversion using entity manager but I can't find the right query method or JPA solution for this. Any suggestions?

The code to the java entity Rate.java is the following:

```
package currency.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author teowey
 */
@Entity
public class Rate implements ConversionDTO, Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer conversionid;

private double rate;
private BigDecimal value;

private String fromCur;
private String toCur;
/**
* Creates a new instance of Account
*/
public Rate() {
}

@Override
public Integer getConversionId() {
    return conversionid;
}

public void setConversionId(Integer conversionid) {
    this.conversionid = conversionid;
}
@Override
public BigDecimal getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setRate(double rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public double getRate(String conversion) {
    return rate;
}

public String getFromCur() {
    return fromCur;
}

public void setFromCur(String from) {
    this.fromCur = from;
}

public String getToCur() {
    return toCur;
}

public void setToCur(String to) {
    this.toCur = to;
}

}
```

Comment: If you get this exception, it simply means that the row you're looking for doesn't exist. Maybe you're querying a different table or schema. Or maybe you didn't commit the changes made to the database.

Comment: The problem is not the database, I configured everything correctly, you can see the screenshot has a table with fromcurrency BRA and to currency EUR in its first row. My problem is getting data from a role and putting it in an Entity object (Rate) to use it as a value in an method. The JPQL query I'm using is not the correct one, I'm having hard time understanding which query and entity manager method to use.

Comment: You didn't post the code of your entity, so it's hard to find a bug there. You're also passing parameters to your query although it doesn't have any. But if the query was invalid, you would get another exception. The exception you got clearly says that the query was executed but didn't return anything.

Comment: Here's the entity code: [link] (https://github.com/teowey/currency-converter/blob/master/src/java/currency/model/Rate.java).

Comment: The code must be **in the question itself**. Not on github.

Comment: Done @JB, thanks :)

Comment: Your screenshot shows that your columns are named fromcurrency and tocurrency. Your entity properties are named fromCur and toCur. So they clearly don't match. So either the table you posted is not the table you're using, or the code is not the code you're using. Not to mention the missing `value` column in the table.

Comment: I will fix the properties. This is my first EJB/JPA project, I will read more in the documentation about Entity. Thanks for the help @JB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to see if there was a tiny issue in the code causing the problem but did not find one.

Here is the method I put under test with some notes and debugging code to assist.

```
// changed input amount to big decimal to avoid floating point issues
public BigDecimal convertTo(String from, String to, BigDecimal value) {

    // changed to validate the currency code - note BRA will fail - need to change to BRL - remove this code if you dont need it.
    Currency fromCurr = Currency.getInstance(from);
    Currency toCurr = Currency.getInstance(to);

    // debugging code - to help troubleshoot (only use this on small table) - will print out the contents of the table so you can see if data is not correct
    List<Rate> rates = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Rate c", Rate.class).getResultList();
    if (rates == null || rates.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("rates table is empty");
    }

    for (Rate r : rates) {
        // push to sysout or whatever logger you are using
        System.out.println(String.format("Rate:fromCur[%s], toCur[%s]", r.getFromCur(), r.getToCur()));
    }
    // end debugging code - remove when no longer needed.

    // changed the query to use bind parameters - :fromCurrency, :toCurrency
    TypedQuery<Rate> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT c FROM Rate c WHERE c.fromCur = :fromCurrency AND c.toCur = :toCurrency", Rate.class);

    query.setParameter("fromCurrency", fromCurr.getCurrencyCode());
    query.setParameter("toCurrency", toCurr.getCurrencyCode());

    Rate rate = query.getSingleResult();
    if (rate == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Can't find rate");
    }

    // changed to use big decimal, scale and rounding as well as avoid floating point issues
    BigDecimal converted =
            value.multiply(rate.getValue()).setScale(toCurr.getDefaultFractionDigits(), RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);

    return converted;
}
```

I included some notes on processing currency to help you avoid potential pitfalls.  Hope this helps you move forward

Comment: Thanks for the help @Bob Lukens, I updated to change the BRA to BRL in the table. I tried your tests and I don't get any error anymore, which is good. However it returns "rates table is empty" from the debugging code `List<Rate> rates = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Rate c", Rate.class).getResultList();`  I'm suspicious that the entity Rate is not correctly implemented. It builds and giver no warning in NetBeans, but the logic must be wrong. Here's the link to the Rate.java code [link] (https://github.com/teowey/currency-converter/blob/master/src/java/currency/model/Rate.java)

Comment: The code appears correct,  if it was not you would get much different exceptions when interacting with the entity manager.

Comment: This might be your issue in the persistence.xml:  `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>` - this is telling JPA to drop and recreate the db each time using the information in the entity.  So if you have or had data in your table,  each time you start the app it may be deleting it all

Comment: Yeah, I changed to value="create", it still doesn't work. I wrote a method viewRates() to output all rates and it doesn't work. In Netbeans if you right-click persistence.xml you can select "Run JPQL Query". It allows you to access the database. So I tested `SELECT c FROM Rate c`, it works and shows all database rows. There's some problem between the web (index.xhtml) and src (currencyManager.java etc.) I suppose.

Comment: I found the problem: Changed the faces-config.xml file. It was missing `<if>#{!currencyManager.getSuccess()}</if>`. The index.xhtml and error.xhtml had wrong EL inside the tags.

Comment: glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve a row data or table data from database using JPQL
just need to implement JPQl Query. In simple way i did this.here my table name is farmer and className is Farmer i used Annotations for database.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManager entityMgr = getEntityManager();
    entityMgr.getTransaction().begin();
    Query q = entityMgr.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Farmer s");

    List<Farmer> list = q.getResultList();
    for(Farmer s:list) {
         System.out.println("Id : "+s.getId()+" Farmer NAME : "+s.getName()+" location : "+s.getVillage());
      }
    entityMgr.getTransaction().commit();
    entityMgr.clear();
}
```